# PHPExcel: Exception "Could not close zip file" on second created file

Tags: php, phpexcel

Fellow community,

I am using an XLSX workbook as a template and dynamically create new workbooks based on it but whenever I try to save a second workbook, the script terminates with fatal error `Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file'`. The error often points to incorrect directory permissions but as mentioned above, the first file is created correctly and opens fine in Excel.

My assumption would be that a reference of some kind is not being unset, that's why I moved the entire reading/saving part to a separate function of my class to not having to deal with unclosed references. Here's part of the code that handles reading and writing:

```
private function createDocument($arrKitInfo, $data) {

    $excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('files/kit/export/order-list-must-points.xlsx');
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $worksheet = $excel->getActiveSheet();

    // skipped: filling in sheet data ...

    $safeFileTitle= FSHelper::createSafeFileName(substr($arrKitInfo['description_en'], 0, 100));
    $destinationFileName= $safeFileTitle.'.xlsx';
    $fileName = sys_get_temp_dir(). $destinationFileName;

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, "Excel2007");
    $objWriter->save($fileName);

    unset($objWriter, $worksheet);

    $excel->disconnectWorksheets();
    unset($excel);
}

// main routine
public function run() {
  foreach ($arrKits as $kit) {
    // ... skipped: load info for the given kit
    $this->createDocument($arrKitInfo, $data);
  }
}
```

The server is running the latest update of PHP 5.2 (most of the applications running on the server are still using `mssql_` functions, migration to an up-to-date PHP version is not an option) and PHPExcel is at 1.7.9.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

-- UPDATE 2015-04 --

It does not seem to be a bug of the ZipArchive module, the following test script did not produce any errors:

```
$intLoops = 6;

for ($intRun = 0; $intRun < $intLoops; $intRun++) {
  $baseArchive = new ZipArchive();
  $destArchive= new ZipArchive();
  $destArchive->open('sample'.$intRun.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
  if ($baseArchive->open('example1.zip')) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $baseArchive->numFiles; $i++) {
      print $baseArchive->getNameIndex($i) . '<br />';
      $destArchive->addFromString($baseArchive->getNameIndex($i), $baseArchive->getFromIndex($i));
    }
  }
  $baseArchive->close();
  $destArchive->close();
  unset($baseArchive);
}
```

Will now try to debug PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 and see if there's more to be found there.

Comment: What's the likelihood that the second filename is the same as the first filename? If a file of the same name already exists, PHPExcel will not be able to overwrite it, and you will get this exception thrown.... it isn't only permissions that can cause this error

Comment: Hi Mark, I had hoped for an answer from you :) The filename can never be the same, the name is constructed using an internal database Id plus additional text. I already played around with a random selection of items, it's always the second file created that is causing the problem.

Comment: In that case, I have no idea.... some obscure bug in PHP's ZipArchive perhaps? The only times I've ever encountered the error have been with permissions, or when trying to save a file that's already open

Comment: @MarkBaker that's what I think, too. Will set up a playground to experiment with ZipArchive's behavior, will let you know what I find out.

Comment: @MarkBaker the error was caused by invisible characters in the used filename, don't know if you want to add control character handling to your writer routines in PHPExcel to circumvent such problems.

Comment: Thanks for the work on identifying the problem... I'll consider adding some validations for the filename (especially as there is a function in PHPExcel to trim non-visible characters from a string), but consider that it should probably really be down to the individual developer rathe rthan the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was not caused by PHPExcel but occurred due to control characters (newline and wordwrap) inside the filename. Checking for invisible characters helped me find the characters:

```
$safeFileTitle = FSHelper::createSafeFileName(substr($arrKitInfo['description_en'], 0, 50));
for ($il=0;$il<strlen($safeFileTitle);$il++) {
  print $safeFileTitle[$il].':'.ord($safeFileTitle[$il]).PHP_EOL;
}
```

I then modified my helper function to remove invisible characters:

```
  public static function createSafeFileName($fileName) {
    // remove all kinds of possibly invalid characters and restrict to characters, digits and whitespace ...
    $fileName = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])", '', $fileName);
    // ... and remove control characters
    return preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $fileName);
  }
```

After the change, the workbooks were created without any problems.